# How to play a streaming audio file using the default audio player in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing a Xamarin app that will simply let the user click a link to a remote audio file, and I'd like the audio file to open in the native, default iOS media player. I don't need any in-app controls - the default audio player's controls will suffice.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this, or am I missing the big picture? I'd take help in either C# or Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the URI you have is a registered handler, you can just use:

```
UIApplication.OpenUrl
```

> [UIKit.UIApplication.OpenUrl](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/UIKit.UIApplication.OpenUrl/) Method Opens the specified URL, launching
>   the app that's registered to handle the scheme.

Also there is [Rivets](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/app-links/app-links-ios/) (a C# port of App Links) that can also be used.

Comment: With a little tweak, this worked great for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked great for me. Thanks to RobertN for the suggestion!

```
var url = NSUrl.FromString(file.Url);
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(url))
{
    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
}
```